# Highlight do VB.NET Esquisito

Tags: bug, status-recusado

[Respondi uma pergunta hoje com código em VB.NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/184881/2999). Quando escrevo comentários em várias linhas, o *highlight* identifica errado o que é código e o que é comentário:

Exemplos:

```
'Não use Try com contexto. Intercepte exceções nos eventos OnException 
'do Controller ou SaveChanges e SaveChangesAsync do contexto.
'Try
```

Ou

```
'Catch ex As Exception
'    trans.Rollback()
'    Throw
```

Comment: Pra constar, no [so] não acontece isso.

Comment: Eu costumo usar assim `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` ou `<!-- language-all: vb -->` mesmo que não precise, isso as vezes ocorre devido as tags... @jbueno Eu presumo que seja porque só tem a tag [tag:vb.net], se tivesse a tag [tag:vba] funcioná (eu fiz o teste no SOen).

Comment: VB.NET, VB e VBA não são a mesma coisa.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez só estou explicando que os sites da rede SE aplicam manualmente o highlight para algumas tags, todo o processo é manual/burocrático, realmente é um bug, mas como eu disse sempre procuro usar o `language:`, tem várias tags que apresentam este problema

Comment: Sim, e como comentei na resposta do @jbueno, queria algo mais bem acabado.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez umas 3 vezes fui no metão pedir coisas do genero, ganhei downvotes e ainda ouvi algumas criticas :( ... vamos ver o que o Gabe pode fazer.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Activia com Johnny Walker. É bug. Acho pertinente colocar aqui.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez afirmativo!

Answer (score 5):

Na verdade, não é um problema com o realce de sintaxe em si, mas sim do mecanismo que define qual realce de sintaxe que vai ser utilizado com base nas tags.

Acontece que as tags [asp.net-mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) e [entity-framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework) prevalecem sobre a [vb.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) e elas têm o realce de sintaxe do C# (aliás, quem é que teve essa ideia?).

A princípio resolve colocando manualmente o realce pra `lang-vb` porque esse é o padrão da tag [vb.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) - o que também é um problema já que são duas linguagens diferentes, mas é o que temos.

Comment: Queria algo mais bem acabado.

Comment: realmente faz sentido